# Formatting Bigdecimal. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, bigdecimal

I want to print `BigDecimal` in TableColumn in my `JavaFx` application. But I can't properly format it.

I've tried this:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
tc_ma_sell_amount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(df.format(cellData.getValue().getSellAmount()).toString()));
```

Format is ok, it prints 1 005 689.56. But problem here is when I sort table according to this column in my application, it refers to this values as if they are Strings and sorting is not correct.

I made following changes:

```
tc_ma_sell_amount.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<BigDecimal>(cellData.getValue().getSellAmount()));
```

Here, format is not ok. (1005689.5600), but sorting works correctly. What do I have to change in order to have right format("#,###.00") and sorting?

Comment: in BigDecimal source ... 

    public String toString() {
        String sc = stringCache;
 if (sc == null)
     stringCache = sc = layoutChars(true);
 return sc;
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it myself.

```
tc_ma_sell_amount.setCellFactory(param -> {
            return new TableCell<ConversionDeals, BigDecimal>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(BigDecimal item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if(empty || item == null){
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        setText(df.format(item));
                    }
                }
            };
        });
```